# Confirming commit message in magit when working with emacsclient

Tags: magit, emacsclient

I am running emacs as client, mostly for the faster startup time.

Now, when I edit a commit message in magit, and confirm it with C-c C-c, not just the window with the commit message is closed, but the entire emacs client (with all the other files I am editing) is terminated, which of course is not what I want.

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: While in the buffer you use to edit the commit message, what is the output of `C-h k C-c C-c` ?

Comment: @TristanRiehs it is "with-editor-finish"...